# Optimal probability mass function with domain $\mathbb N^+$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, optimization, linear-programming

Given *nonnegative* infinite sequence $\left( y_k \right)_{k \geq 1}$ with $\displaystyle\sum_{k \geq 1} y_k = 1$, solve the optimization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \displaystyle\sum_{k \geq 1} k \, x_k \, y_k\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\sum_{k \geq 1} k \, x_k = a\\ & \displaystyle\sum_{k \geq 1} x_k = 1\\ & x_k \geq 0\end{array}$$

What about the infinite sequence $\left( x_k \right)_{k \geq 1}$ that minimizes the sum?

I made this problem up.  I am interpreting $\left( x_k \right)_{k \geq 1}$ and $\left( y_k \right)_{k \geq 1}$ as probability distributions over the positive integers and $a$ is an expected value. My guess is this type of problem has been well studied, which is why I am asking here. Thank you.

**Edit:**

After doing some research, it appears that the above problem may have a solution which can be computed with linear programming.  However, there is little to no chance of there being a nice form for the solution if the $y_n's$ are arbitrary.

So to make the problem more manageable, I posted a modified problem:

[Optimization of Probability Mass Function Linear Programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556579/optimization-of-probability-mass-function-linear-programming)

Comment: If $a$ is large enough, the sum seems to be minimized by setting $N = \text{arg}\min_{n \le a} ny_n$ and set $x_N = 1$ and 0 elsewhere. Then this satisfying $\sum x_n = 1$ and $\sum n x_n = N \le a$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete answer, but I'll go ahead and share my thoughts...

We cannot have $a < 1$, because this implies the problem is infeasible.

If $a = 1$, the only feasible solution is $x_1 = 1$.

If $a > 1$, let $j \equiv \arg \max_k k y_k$ (assuming there is a maximum). There are then 3 sub-cases to consider:

1. If $j = a$, set $x_j = 1$.  You are done.
2. If $j < a$, the optimal value is not achieved, but is approached by a sequence of solutions of the form $x_j = 1 - \delta$, $x_n = \delta$, where $\delta$ satisfies $n \delta + j(1-\delta)=a$.  As $n$ increases, $\delta$ decreases, and the objective value approaches $j y_j$.
3. If $j > a$... I don't know.

Comment: I think that, unfortunately, the problem is much more complicated (see my answer). First of all, because we have two conditions to satisfy, we have to maximize with respect not to one index, but to two. Next, we need a lot of subtle technical arguments in order to prove that we indeed will reach a supremum this way.

Comment: Agreed, I now also believe my handling of sub-case 3 was incorrect.  Do you agree with sub-case 2?

Answer (score 1):

Let $M\le a$ be the supremum of the sum $f(x)=\sum_{k \geq 1} k \, x_k \, y_k$, where a vector $x=(x_k)$ satisfies the given conditions. We claim that

$$M=M’=\sup\left\{\frac{(a-m)ny_n-(a-n)my_m}{n-m}: m\le a\le n, m\ne n \right\}.$$

Indeed, if $m<n$,  $x_m+x_n=1$ and $mx_m+nx_n=a$ then $x_m=\frac{n-a}{n-m}$ and $x_n=\frac{a-m}{n-m}$. The numbers  $x_m$ and $x_n$ are non-negative iff $m\le a\le n$. Thus $M\ge M’$.

On the other hand let $\varepsilon>0$ be an arbitrary number and  $x$ be a vector $x=(x_k)$ satisfying the conditions such that $f(x)<M-\varepsilon$. Pick a number $N’$ such that $\sum_{k>N’} kx_ky_k<\varepsilon$. Put $s_1=\sum_{k>N’} x_k$ and $s_a=\sum_{k>N’} kx_k$. If $s_1=0$ put $N=N’$, otherwise put $$N=\lceil s_a/s_1\rceil+1\ge s_a/s_1+1\ge N’+2.$$

Let $x’=(x’_1,\dots, x’_N)$ be a solution of the following optimization problem O

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^N k \, x’_k \, y_k\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^N k \, x’_k = a \\ & \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^N x’_k = 1\\ & x’_k \geq 0\end{array},$$

containing the smallest number $n_0$ of non-zero coordinates. We claim that $n_0$ is at most two. Indeed, assume that for some distinct indices $l$, $m$, and $n$  each of $x’_l$, $x’_m$, $x’_n$ is postive. Fix all $x’_k$’s, but $x’_l$, $x’_m$, $x’_n$, put $s’_1=1-\sum_{k\ne l, m, n} x’_k$,  $s’_a=1-\sum_{k\ne l, m, n} kx’_k$, and consider  the following optimization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & \displaystyle l\bar x_ly_l+ m\bar x_my_m+ n\bar x_ny_n\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle l\bar x_l+ m\bar x_m + n\bar x_n=s’_a \\ & \displaystyle \bar x_l+ \bar x_m +\bar x_n=s'_1 \\ & \bar x_l, \bar x_m, \bar x_n\geq 0\end{array}.$$

In this problem we have to find a maximum of a linear function $$f(\bar x_l, \bar x_m, \bar x_n)= l\bar x_ly_l+ m\bar x_my_m+ n\bar x_ny_n$$ on an intersection of a triangle $T$ defined by conditions $$\bar x_l+ \bar x_m +\bar x_n=s’_1\mbox{ , }\bar x_l, \bar x_m, \bar x_n\geq 0$$ with a plane defined by an equation $$l\bar x_l+ m\bar x_m + n\bar x_n=s’_a.$$ Such a intersection can be either a segment (then the maximum of $f$ is attained in one of its endpoints) or the triangle $T$ (then the maximum of $f$ is attained in one of its vertices). Anyway, the maximum is attained in a point $(\bar x_l, \bar x_m, \bar x_n)$ belonging to a plane defined by one of the following equation $\bar x_l=0$, $\bar x_m=0$, or $\bar x_n=0$. Now define a vector $\bar x=(\bar x_1,\dots, \bar x_N)$ by putting $\bar x_k=x’_k$ for each $k$ distinct from $l,m,n$. Then $\bar x$ is a solution of the problem having less non-zero coordinates than $n_0$,
which contradicts its minimality. Thus $n_0\le 2$.

Now put $x^*=(x^*_k)$, where $x^*_k=x’_k$, if $k\le N$, and $x^*_k=0$, otherwise. 
Since $x^*_m+x^*_n=1$ and $mx^*_m+nx^*_n=a$, we see that $f(x^*)\le M’$.

Now we construct a vector $x’’=(x’’_1,\dots, x’’_N)$ satisfying the constraints of the problem O as follows. Put $x’’_k=x_k$ for each $k\le N’$. If $s_1=0$ then put $x’’_k=0$ for the remaining $k$. Otherwise determine $x’’_{N’+1}$ and $x’’_N$ from the system $$x’’_{N’+1}+x’’_N=s_1\mbox{ and }(N’+1)x’’_{N’+1}+Nx’’_N=s_a,$$ so we have $$x’’_{N’+1}=\frac {Ns_1-s_a}{N-N’-1}\ge 0\mbox{ and }x’’_N=\frac {s_a-(N’+1)s_1}{N-N’-1}\ge 0,$$ and put $x’’_k=0$ for the remaining indices. Put $x^{**}=(x^{**}_k)$, where $x^{**}_k=x’’_k$, if $k\le N$, and $x^{**}_k=0$, otherwise. Thus we have
$$M’\ge f(x^*)\ge f(x^{**})\ge f(x)-\sum_{k>N’} kx_ky_k>M-\varepsilon-\varepsilon=M-2\varepsilon.$$

Since the number $\varepsilon$ can be chosen arbitrarily small, we have $M=M’$.